# regx for python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7

I am writing regx for removing test qualifier and extra delimiter from the string.

I have some pattern as below,

```
"ID"~"Name"~"DESC"
1~2014~13~"DS"~DF"
1~2014~13~"DS"~"DF" 
"1ABCA~B C"~"ERTE"
"2"~"XYZ"~"ABC~ is~ bother"
"3"~"YYZ"~"MEL O CRÈME DOUGHNUTS RECLASS"
4~"XAA"~"sf~sd sdfsf"
5~"TES"~"SFSFSF"sdfsf"
6~"ABC"SDDSL~"dfadf"
```

the expected output is,

```
ID~Name~DESC
1~2014~13~DS~DF
1~2014~13~DS~DF
1ABCA B C~ERTE
2~XYZ~ABC  is  bother
3~YYZ~MEL O CRÈME DOUGHNUTS RECLASS
4~XAA~sf sd sdfsf
5~TES~SFSFSF"sdfsf
6~ABCSDDSL~dfadf
```

I have written below code for the same,

```
import re

delimiter = '~'
pattern = re.compile(r'"' + delimiter + r'"')
pattern1 = re.compile(r'"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"')

with open("source file path here ", "r") as \
        test:
    for line in test:
        fields = re.split(pattern, line)
        print(fields)
        output = ""
        if re.match('^[^"]', line):
            matches = re.findall(pattern1, line)
            print(matches)
            for match in matches:
                line = re.sub(match, re.sub('^["]|["]$', "", match), line)
            print(line)
        else:
            lastfield = fields[-1]
            for field in fields:
                if field != lastfield:
                    field = re.sub('^["]|["]$', "", field)
                    output = output + re.sub('[' + delimiter + ']', " ", field) \
                        + delimiter
                else:
                    field = re.sub('^["]|["]$', "", field)
                    output = output + re.sub('[' + delimiter + ']', " ", field)
        print(output)
```

looking for optimize way to do this and the code which will handle all the patterns.

Comment: Why is the second line expected to turn into `1~2014~13~DS~DF`?  The last `"` is not paired. Or should the third quite or more remain in the last field?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because while loading this data into system it will create problem so wanted to remove quotes which are not part of the data. This is data level issue which we need to handle.

Comment: Could you please write the rules for replacement in the question? Should `1~2014~13~DS~DF` be really duplicated?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry this is my fault I miss one pattern to write which is 1~2014~13~"DS"~"DF"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the rules are remove unwanted delimiter and quotes which are not part of data if quotes are coming as part of string we need to keep that as data is immutable.

Comment: There is still a confusion here: if the last `"` on the second line should be gone, why should it stay in the last but one? Sorry, this question is unclear, and only you can answer it. We do not know how you define what is "immutable" and what is "unwanted".

Comment: We're gonna need a spec of your format ... and I mean spec... not just a simple description. Otherwise this is way too unclear...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There are two types of data numeric and string we received lot of files some of which contains double quotes for numeric as well as string data and also there are few files which contains double quotes for string only. The problem is if data contains extra delimiter we need to handle this and if there is quotes in string we need to keep that as it is. Sometimes due to some issue quotes may be missing at beginning or ending we need handle that as well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew on the second line quotes are at the end of string means it is invalid and need to remove if you look at last one quotes are present in string this is the difference.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your sample output does not match up with the input (why is the second line duplicated?), you are not really asking a question. Please specify the problem with your code. "looking for optimize way" - please specify what problem you spotted while profiling. Or are you just looking for somebody to [review your code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @mroman look into above two comments if still it is unclear let me know will provide problem statement in details.

Comment: @rudd helderman I have already mentioned in the first comment that by mistake I missed one line so it is showing duplicate line.

Comment: Why `1ABCA B C~ERTE` is expected from `"1ABCA~B C"~"ERTE"`? I would expect `"1ABCA~B C~ERTE`. Same about `2~XYZ~ABC  is  bother` - I would expect `2~XYZ~ABC~ is~ bother`. I can't get the "formula". I tried https://ideone.com/4qlIks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew first you can split fields using double quotes and delimiter in above example, "2"~"XYZ"~"ABC~ is~ bother" if you split you will get "2" "XYZ"   "ABC~is~bother" here if remove double quotes and load data as it is will create problem as last part having extra delimiter while loading will get split in three columns. so whatever delimiter coming within quotes that's is extra and need to remove.

Comment: If you say `~` between quotes should be removed, then `4~"XAA"~"sf~sd sdfsf"` should turn into `4~XAA~sf sd sdfsf`, why do you expect `4~XAA~sf~sd sdfsf`? I tried https://ideone.com/j9f6EH.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes you are right.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew saw your code at ideone.com/j9f6EH. could you please explain.

Comment: I remove `~` chars in between field qualifiers (double quotes) and then remove all  `"` that have no `"`  or `~` to the end of the field (not sure it is what you need, hence still hesitating to post as an  answer).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew post your answer have seen that i think its working so post the answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may remove all `~` inside field qualifiers with

```
(?m)(?:(?<=^)|(?<=~))"(.*?)"(?=$|~)
```

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `re.M` mode on to make `^` match start of line and `$` to match end of line (remove if the strings are processed line by line)
- `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=~))` - start of line or a position immediately preceded with `~`
- `"` - a double quote
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than newline, as few as possible
- `"` - a double quote
- `(?=$|~)` - end of line or a location immediately followed with `~`.

and then remove all unnecessary double quotes with

```
(?m)(?:(?<=^)|(?<=~))"|"(?=$|~)|"(?=[^\n"~]+(?:~|$))
```

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `re.M` modifier (remove if the strings are processed line by line)
- `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=~))"` - a double quote at the start of a line or right after `~`
- `"(?=$|~)|` - a `"` at the end of the line or before `~`
- `"(?=[^\n"~]+(?:~|$))` - a `"` followed with 1 or more chars other than LF (remove if the strings are processed line by line), `"` and `~` and then `~` or end of line.

Thins one may  be used to match substrings and then remove all `~` with spaces using `.replace('~', ' ')` inside the replace callback method.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/j9f6EH):

```
import re
rx_0 = r"""(?m)(?:(?<=^)|(?<=~))"(.*?)"(?=$|~)"""
rx = r"""(?m)(?:(?<=^)|(?<=~))"|"(?=$|~)|"(?=[^\n"~]+(?:~|$))"""
s = ("\"ID\"~\"Name\"~\"DESC\"\n"
    "1~2014~13~\"DS\"~DF\"\n"
    "1~2014~13~\"DS\"~\"DF\"\n"
    "\"1ABCA~B C\"~\"ERTE\"\n"
    "\"2\"~\"XYZ\"~\"ABC~ is~ bother\"\n"
    "\"3\"~\"YYZ\"~\"MEL O CRÈME DOUGHNUTS RECLASS\"\n"
    "4~\"XAA\"~\"sf~sd sdfsf\"\n"
    "5~\"TES\"~\"SFSFSF\"sdfsf\"\n"
    "6~\"ABC\"SDDSL~\"dfadf\"")

print( re.sub(rx, "", re.sub(rx_0, lambda x: x.group(1).replace('~', ' '), s)))
```

Output:

```
ID~Name~DESC
1~2014~13~DS~DF
1~2014~13~DS~DF
1ABCA B C~ERTE
2~XYZ~ABC  is  bother
3~YYZ~MEL O CRÈME DOUGHNUTS RECLASS
4~XAA~sf sd sdfsf
5~TES~SFSFSFsdfsf
6~ABC"SDDSL dfadf
```